# why cant i start xsesion

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xorg, xserver

I have a tripple boot configuration(windows on sda1(ssd 256 gb) ubuntu on sdb2(hdd 500 gb) on my laptop and kali on sdb3 and after i resized sda4 so i could have a school partition acessable from any os and now i cant start xserver o ubuntu because it cant lock .Xauthority file, it wont even start using startx

[sdb partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36OKt.png)

[sda partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOd0B.png)

[xserver error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa9WZ.png)